# How do I execute a bash command with I/O redirection?

Tags: linux

In Unix environment, I can execute a command e.g `./getall.tcl xcm_in.txt > xcm_out.txt` where `getall.tcl` is the software script, `xcm_in.txt` is the input file and `xcm_out.txt` is the output file which will be generated.

How can do it in the Linux environment?

Comment: Please clarify your question. The answer to your literal question ("Can I do [....]?") is obviously yes. What do you need to know exactly? How to accept input? How to produce output? How to write a script? Have you tried? Are you experiencing a problem doing input or output? It's vague.

Comment: The same as on the Unix environment. Just ensure that you have a Tcl interpreter installed.

Answer (score 4):

Linux is derived from UNIX so you do it exactly in the same way: `./getall.tcl xcm_in.txt > xcm_out.txt`

- `getall.tcl` is the command you're calling (apparently a Tcl script)
- `xcm_in.txt` is the file passed as argument to the command
- `xcm_out.txt` is the file to which the command's stdout is redirected

Comment: Pedantically, Linux is *an implementation of* Unix, rather than *derived from*.  It provides the same (POSIX) interfaces, but does not get its implementation from SysV or BSD Unix.  You still get an upvote from me, because the substance of your answer is spot on.